# set height and width value with Negative value?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

for some convincing reasons i need change width and height of some images in my page to Negative values (with javascript function), but i saw in browser its not going under zero. is it possible to do something like this ?

Comment: What exactly does a negative width/height mean? If a square has a height of `-1` what does that even represent?

Comment: What are the convincing reasons?

Comment: I have many pictures with different value of width and height, my function goes them to zero, when i want turn back them to their original size they all got one size

Answer (score 2):

No, and I don't see why there would be any reason to, if they're at 0 they won't be visible, so what would be the meaning of negative width/heights?

Comment: I have many pictures with different value of width and height, my function goes them to zero, when i want turn back them to their original size (with same algorithm) they all got one size

Comment: So you want to save their original size as negative values, to be able to retrieve them later..?

Comment: Yes, i want my function continue and change size to negative, so i can turn them back to size they were (my function runs more than one time )

Comment: Could you set display: none; on the image(s) and then set height/width to original dimensions?

Comment: problem is here i don't have original dimensions (its not original dimensions of images) i just know the algorithm make them smaller ! function change dimensions of all images with one algorithm and its run more than one time. so smaller images sooner be at 0 width/heights and when i run reverse function problem appear. I want user see process of change images size

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand but what if you run the algorithm without settings the width/heights to see if the image doesn't become to small...

Comment: i think about save all dimensions in an array, and work with that values